A print statement is moving to the next line before it should
While working on an assignment i had to break apart a file and put it into a dictionary using multiple values per key, the print statement at the end called apon specific values under each key and after pulling the value in the 2nd slot of keys it moves to the next line for no apparent reson i can tell.
the code i wrote is
`moviefile = open(input())
file = moviefile.readlines()
mov_dict = {}
for line in file:
    tokens = line.split(',')
    if tokens[1] in mov_dict:
        mov_dict.setdefault(tokens[1],[]).extend([tokens[0]])
    else:
        mov_dict.setdefault(tokens[1],[]).extend([tokens[0], tokens[2]])
for title in mov_dict:
    print(f'{title:44} |{mov_dict[title][1]:>5} |', end='')`

the last print statement moves to the next line after {mov_dict[title][1]:>5} makint the output look like
Wonders of the World                         |   G
|Journey to Space                             |PG-13
when i expected
Wonders of the World                         |   G |Journey to Space                             |PG-13
